# Service cannot access folder

Tags: delphi, service, firebird

I've made a service to do backups of firebird databases using Delphi.
The service basically gets a destination dir and create a FBK file using GBAK.
Works well in any directory except of the "Google Drive" directory, and i don't know how to solve it.

When i execute GBAK separately from the service, it works so i don't know what is going wrong

Here's some code

```
if not FileExists(GetEnvironmentVariable('ProgramData') + '\MY\' + Nombre) then
try
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  with SEInfo do
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := 0;
    lpFile := PWIDEChar(RegQueryStringValue('SOFTWARE\Firebird Project\Firebird Server\Instances', 'DefaultInstance') + 'bin\gbak.exe');
    nShow := SW_HIDE;
    lpParameters := PWIDEChar('-v -t -user SYSDBA -password "masterkey" MY ' + '"' + GetEnvironmentVariable('ProgramData') + '\MY\' + Nombre + '"');
  end;
  if ShellExecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    repeat
      GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCD);
    until (ExitCD <> STILL_ACTIVE) or (Terminated);
  end;
except
  on e: Exception do
  begin
    if GetLastError <= 32 then
    begin
      case GetLastError of
        0, se_err_OOM:
          InsertError('OutMem', error_1);
        error_File_Not_Found:
          InsertError('GMiss', error_2);
        error_Path_Not_Found:
          InsertError('Path', error_3);
        error_Bad_Format:
          InsertError('GBreak', error_4);
        se_err_AccessDenied:
          InsertError('AccX', error_5);
        se_err_NoAssoc, se_err_AssocIncomplete:
          InsertError('BadFile', error_6);
        se_err_DDEBusy, se_err_DDEFail, se_err_DDETimeOut:
          InsertError('DDE', error_7);
        se_err_Share:
          InsertError('Share', error_8);
        else
          InsertError('Unkn', error_9);
      end;
      MYBackup.Status := csStopped;
      Exit;
    end
    else
    begin
      InsertError(e.ClassName, e.Message);
      MYBackup.Status := csStopped;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: what error do you receive?

Comment: None, it seems to work but does nothing

Comment: Which paths work, and which don't (literal paths please)?

Comment: 1) SysInternals Process Monitor - and see what error do you receive // 2) gbak failures might be in firebird log file // check which user FB service runs from and whether that user is granted access to your folder 4) that code of yours works, so why bother. Where is the code that fails ? 5) What Windows and Firebird version do you use? Do you use fbclient.dll or fbembed.dll as a client library ?

Comment: The path that fails is "C:\Users\Boris\Google Drive\Ismael-Trabajo"
I don't recive any error, it's like it's working, but nothing happens, and i don't know where is the code that fails.
I'm on windows 7 ultimate servicepack 1 and i'm using fbclient.dll

Comment: Like Arioch said, use Procmon and search for your path, chances are big you receive ACCESS DENIED or something like that. If that is that case, it means that the SYSTEM user has no access to this path. A possible solution is to run the service with administrative credentials (logon tab).

Comment: yet you did not named FB version, nor if u use 32-bit or 64-bit version of FB nor if you use 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows... //So you answered only half of question 5 and none of the other questions. If you choose to conceal information from us then we cannot help you.

Comment: My guess is that the account the service is running under has no rights to the user folder. I notice your code does not check the exit code returned from GetExitCodeProcess and seems to be relying on it raising an exception. Try logging that somewhere and see what happens. You could also try logging in with an account that has the same privileges as the SYSTEM account (or whatever account your service is executing under) and try and create a text file in C:\Users\Boris. My guess is you won't even be able to find the folder in the first place.

Comment: Ok, trying things i've come to the conclusion that it's, how most of you say, a permission problem. The thing is that i don't know how to give net permissions to the service so it can connect to network folders.
Any ideas?

Comment: Windows services have no direct access to mapped network folders, but I have successfully tried to execute net use from a c# service. In Delphi you should be able to do the same with ShellExecute.

Comment: you could try something like shellexecute(0,'open','net','use x: \\computer\share','',sw_minimize); (not tested)

Comment: just being curious, did this solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Google Drive usually restricts access to the folder to the user that created the folder. Your Service most likely runs as LocalSystem. Just check the folder permissions (Properties / Security)